# Prove absolute and uniform convergence on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, uniform-convergence, absolute-convergence

Consider the series $$\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\pi i [n^2 \tau + 2n z]},$$ where Im$(\tau) >0$ and $z \in \mathbb{C}$. Prove that this series converges absolutely and uniformly on compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$.

The compact subsets of $\mathbb{C}$ are those subsets which are closed and bounded. Moreover, with some algebraic manipulation, we obtain the following:

$$\left| \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{\pi i [n^2 \tau + 2nz]} \right| \leq \left| e^{\pi i n^2 \tau} \right| \cdot \left| \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} e^{2 \pi i nz} \right| \leq \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} \left| e^{2\pi i} \right|^{nz} \leq \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} 1^{nz}.$$ From here however, I'm unsure of how to continue.

Comment: $$\left|e^{2\pi inz}\right|=e^{-2\pi n\,\text{Im}\,z}$$ and the problem now is that the imaginary part of $\;z\;$ isn't restricted somehow...

Comment: Look at $\sum_n q^{n^2} r^n$ the ratio test shows it converges whenever $|q| < 1$ and [your series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function#Jacobi_theta_function) converges absolutely whenever $|e^{i \pi \tau}| < 1$ i.e. whenever $Im(\tau) > 0$

Comment: For $z=0$ and $\tau =i/n^2$, the terms of the series satisfy $e^{i\pi n^2\tau}=e^{-\pi}$.  Therefore, the series cannot uniformly converge for $\text{Im}(\tau)>0$.  However, for all $\delta >0$ and $\text{Im}(\tau)>\delta$, the series does converge uniformly.

Comment: @Dr.MV (if $Im(\tau) > 0$ as stated by the OP) $f_\tau(z)$ [converges compactly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence) (uniformly on any compact) but not uniformly

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, I agree.  I believe that my comment elucidates this, does it not?

Comment: @user1952009 Oh, I see now

Comment: @Dr.MV that was to say the compact convergence is the one we always consider in complex-analysis, since it ensures the limit is analytic (and we almost never have the uniform convergence)

Comment: @user1952009 Yes, I see that now.